# Can't drag items from a ListView in my Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am creating my very first Windows Phone 8.1 app as part of a Windows Store Universal app. The Desktop/tablet version is done and has been in the store for a few weeks, and it works great. I'm being careful and assuming as little as possible as I build out the Phone version, and I have had reasonable success so far. However, there is one problem that I just haven't been able  to sort out through experimentation, Stackoverflow or Google: I can't get items in a ListView to be draggable.

Here's a shot of one of the pages from my app:

[image: New Workout page from Solo Coach app]

The user creates a workout routine by dragging exercises from the ListView on the right-hand side to the area on the left-hand side. They can drag an exercise as many times as they want; that's why it's not just a single list on which items can be checked.

This works perfectly on the desktop/tablet version, but on the phone version, when I click and hold an item, I can't drag it anywhere. It won't move, and it doesn't show any affordance to indicate that it is draggable.

Here is the XAML that I use to define the ListView. It is nearly identical to the working version, but I have turned on some properties that aren't present there (`IsSwipeEnabled` I think), hoping that they would make the magic work:

```
    <ListView x:Name="StepsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
              ContainerContentChanging="ItemView_ContainerContentChanging"
              SelectionMode="Single" Drop="StepsList_Drop"
              Tapped="StepsList_Tapped"
              CanDragItems="True" 
              AllowDrop="True"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              DragItemsStarting="StepsList_DragItemsStarting"
              Margin="5,0"
              IsSwipeEnabled="True"
              SelectionChanged="StepsList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300" />
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300" />
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:StepControl Role="StepsSource" Tapped="StepSourceItem_Tapped" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I put a break point inside the `DragItemsStarting` event handler code, and it is never hit.

Comment: I tried to convert another sample to WP8.1 and had no success either. An extended search only turned up a few other remarks about it not working...

Comment: Any success with this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: I have not had any success, and in fact I have temporarily abandoned my project. I was very enthusiastic about having a Windows Universal app (the non-Phone version works great), but it seems to me that Phone 8.1 lags badly behind the rest of the platform and just seems buggy. I'm hugely disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it in the code behind.

```
StepsList.ReorderMode =  ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN documentation for dragging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632429.aspx) shows that only the Windows 8.1 app will support it unfortunately.

Edit: Having delved deeper, it seems it should be supported through Universal app development across both platforms. Does the dragging functionality work in your Windows 8.1 app?